# Show me new questions since my last visit?

Tags: feature-request

> Duplicate of [**Show me new questions since my last visit?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65704/show-me-new-questions-since-my-last-visit) on *[meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)*

Gaming SE's question count is still pretty low, which makes me want to read all the new questions and hope I can help someone. Is there a way to show questions new since my last visit? If not can we add this feature?

EDIT - [asked on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65704/show-me-new-questions-since-my-last-visit), prepare the flame suit.